# HTML table with XPath in php

Tags: php, xpath

I was try so many ways to extract table from:

https://secure.tickertech.com/bnkinvest/cgi/?a=historical&ticker=IVV&w=dividends

I was using DOM, xpath and all other things found on stackoverflow, none of them work :/

Can anyone give me some ideas how to get that table?

Is nested ... and don't have any ID as selector, i run out of ideas ...

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://secure.tickertech.com/bnkinvest/cgi/?a=historical&ticker=IVV&w=dividends");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// It's rare you'll have valid XHTML, suppress any errors- it'll do its best.
@$doc->loadhtml($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Modify the XPath query to match the content
foreach($xpath->query('//table')->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $rows) {
    $cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
    if($cells->lenght() ==2)
    {
        print_r($cells);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can show what you have tried so far, I'm sure someone may be able to help.

Comment: print_r($xpath->query('//html/body/p[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table'));

0 results ... in array

Comment: If you get the path from a browser, it can add it's own elements - the document doesn't contain and tbody tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adjusted the XPath to try and ensure you get the right table, but as you say there isn't any id or class to distinguish it.  This will look for a nested table which has tr and td combinations.  Then using virtually the same code as you currently have to check if there are 2 columns and then outputting the data...

```
foreach( $xpath->query('//table[1]//table//table/tr[td]') as $rows) {
    $cells = $rows->getElementsByTagName('td');
    if($cells->length ==2)
    {
        echo $cells[0]->textContent."=>".$cells[1]->textContent.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, got it! ... its s loop, in loop using xpath, then validate for 2 cell size ... thanks!